# Forecasting with plm [panel regression]

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, plm

I am having some troubles with forecasting panel data using the fixed model of the `plm` pachage. I know that it does not have a built-in forecasting function, so I want to compute the out-of-sample forecasts by hand. Is my logic correct:

```
fixed <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=panel_df, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")

forecast <- fixed$coefficients[1] * x1 + 
            fixed$coefficients[2] * x2 + 
            as.numeric(fixef(fixed))
```

Of course, as this is out-of-sample forecasting, I am using lagged variables (already defined in the data.frame `panel_df`), and for the forecasting I use the last observations, which should give forecasts for the one-ahead (unknown) period.

I would be grateful for confirming whether such approach is correct!